# mysql selection lost data with data concurrent

Tags: mysql, rest, api, cakephp-2.3

I create an API (CakePHP2.7) which insert batch of data and response back all new added data. Now, I am having problem with response (select) losing some data.
I tried to make 2 transaction which each transaction insert 20 records at the same time. After both transaction completed

- my first transaction : response new added data 40 records
- my second transaction : response new added data only 20 recode.

I see the records of data for both transaction insert to database is not order. I wonder why second transaction cannot get any data of first transaction?

Is there any way that I can get all data for both transaction without losing any data?

Please help me, I don't have much knowledge about database or api. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help us help you if you include the bit of code that saves the rows and then returns them as a response. Also, your tests don't make sense. If the first request/transation has 20 rows/records, how can it return 40 ?